# My game works fine in pc but when i play in mobile it looks like 15fps. But 60fps (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I created a online mobile game with photon (unity) . It was working successfully. But something happened and now in its look like low fps. But i checked it and fps counter showed me 60fps. I tried nearly everything for it but i couldn't fix it. (Yes i checked camera update)

Comment: Your pc likely has way more power than a mobile

Comment: I know that but the problem isn't fps or performance